# Fluent Validations. Error: Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I got the erorr:

> Validation type names in unobtrusive
>   client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type
>   was seen more than once: required. The
>   following validation type was seen
>   more than once: required

I used server validation. And all worked fine. 
But now I`m stating to use client-side validation and I got this problem.

This is my validation class code:

```
public class TestViewDataValidation : BaseTestCreateViewDataValidation<BaseTestCreateViewData>
    {

public TestViewDataValidation ()
        {
            this.RuleFor(x => x.Login).NotNull();
            this.RuleFor(x => x.Login).NotEmpty();
            this.RuleFor(x => x.Login).EmailAddress();          
        }
}
```

But if I leave one validator - all works fine. 
What should I do to have more that one validation for field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`FluentValidation.NET` is called *Fluent* because it provides a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for chaining methods:

```
public TestViewDataValidation()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Login)
        .NotNull()
        .NotEmpty()
        .EmailAddress();
}
```

Remark: the usage of `NotNull` and `NotEmpty` rules seem reduntant to me in this case. `NotEmpty` should be enough.

Answer (score 28):

This error is shown if you have the same validation on the same element more than once.

Not setting `AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false` for both the default DataAnnontations *and* your FluentValidation will add a Required validation on any ValueTypes (like an `int`). If you at the same time add a RuleFor (or a `[Required]` attribute) on any ValueType you will have an extra Required for that field.

For that reason (I want to set all validations explicitly) I have the following in my `Application_Start()`:

```
var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory());
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider);
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
```

Comment: Like Darin is saying, adding NotNull and NotEmpty *is* redundant, and not only that. It enforces the same validation twice, hence the error i described here in my post...

Comment: somehow, this don't work for clientside validation only for serverside..on client side asp.net mvc emit required attributes on all fields no matter that I set AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes to false :( I ask similira to this on this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011615/clientside-validation-attributes-on-hidden-radio-dropdown-elements-by-default-i

 and didn't get answer...am I doing something wrong or validation rules and logic are inconstant on server and on client?? thanx