# RIA/EF4 Entity property mapped to NOT NULL nvarchar - empty string

Tags: silverlight, string, entity-framework, ria

**Background:**

- Entity Framework 4
- Silverlight 4
- RIA services
- MSSQL Server 2008

I have an entity that has a String property named Description.

In database it maps to the `NOT NULL NVARCHAR(200)`.

**Problem:**

When I try to insert a new row of that entity, this is what I do:

```
MyExampleEntity entity = new MyExampleEntity()
{
    Name = "example",
    Description = ""        // NOTE THIS LINE!
};

DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
db.MyExampleEntities.Add(entity);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

This, however, causes an exception saying `"The Description field is required."`

**Question:**

Should not the "empty string" be simply that - **a string with zero characters**?

I believe only **`Description = null`** should be treated as providing **no value**.

- Why is my string, which has a value (although its length is 0), considered to be as if I have omitted the value?
- On what level does this conversion happen? On RIA, on EF or in MSSQL?
- Is there a way to make a description have zero-length value when I set the `Description to ""` and cause an exception when `Description = null` (having no value)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a symptom of Entity Framework.

[Related Article](http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-pass-empty-string-in-entity.html)

Some data annotations can be used to overcome this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Report_META))]
   public partial class Report
   {
   }

   public partial class Report_META
   {
       [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
       [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
       public object Note { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `[Required]` attribute might collide with FluentValidation rules if you're using those, since these can add the attribute as well, and you can only have one instance of the attribute at a time ([http://stackoverflow.com/a/5552237/1454265](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5552237/1454265)). I was able to get around this and allow empty strings by dropping the `[Required]` attribute from the MetadataType class and adding a conditional rule to the validation: `RuleFor(x => x.Field).Etc(...).When(x => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.Field);`