# Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, unobtrusive-validation

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type was seen more than once:
>   required

This is referring to the EmailAddress property, here:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("Style", "Wide")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("Style", "Wide")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not using the same type of validation rule twice here. This works fine locally, but not when deployed to the server. What's the deal?

I did add a reference to `DataAnnotationExtensions` ([http://dataannotationsextensions.org](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/)), could that be causing an issue?

**Edit:** removing the reference did not fix the problem. It seems something may be messed up with the IIS configuration?

Comment: I'm also using dataannotationsextensions and am not having any issues. The only difference I see is that you have the "AdditionalMetadata" attribute in use which I've never used. Try removing it and see if it still errors?

Comment: No luck. This code all worked fine before (I haven't changed this model). Works fine locally, just not when deployed to the server.

Comment: I found this link, it may shed some light. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/workitem/7072

Comment: Hmmm. I did try the suggestion to no avail. But I'm not using the Fluent library.

Comment: Removing `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>` and `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` from the `appSettings` in the root `Web.config` fixed the problem.

Comment: I saw someone else say that fixed the problem too but you lose client side validation by doing that. If you can live without it then it's not a problem. But it would be better for performance to not have to post the model to the server just to run model validation and return back to the client if it fails.

Comment: This is a weird case for me. I have the root `Web.config` which points to another config file, `\Configuration\[Region]\AppSettings.config`. I removed the aforementioned settings from this file. They do, however still exist in the `\Views\Web.config` file. However, it does appear that JS validation is not currently working. Which I DO want to work so I guess I have some more digging to do!

Comment: Show Your View too.please.

Comment: Late to this (to say the least), but... In your controller, could you do a watch/trace of the contents of `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers`? `HTMLHelper` (which is what throws this error) only gets unobtrusive validation rules by consulting those providers, and if `DataAnnotationExtensions` isn't causing it (and we'll assume the default `DataAnnotationModelValidatorProvider` isn't causing it by itself either), there should be another provider inthere, for this error to occur.

Comment: What version is your local IIS and what version is the server's?

Comment: are you using FluentValidation or some DI?

Comment: hmm, was getting the same error...also removed those two things from the web.config and fixed it. I have no clue.

Answer (score 20):

[JimmiTh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746186/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique#comment26469383_9746186) on the question provided a key insight for me to resolve this for myself.

In my case, I definitely did add an additional provider to `ModelValidatorProviders`. I added a custom validation factory (using [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com)) with this code in my *Global.asax.cs* file:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
    new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(validatorFactory));
```

But using multiple providers isn't *necessarily* problematic. What seems to be problematic is if multiple providers provide the same validators, because that will register the same rules multiple times, causing the mentioned problem with the Microsoft unobtrusive validation code.

I ended up removing the following line from the same file as I decided I didn't need to use both providers:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

The `Configure` method above is itself adding a provider to `ModelValidatorProviders`, and I was effectively registering the same validator class twice, hence the error about non-unique "validation type names".

The SO question [jquery - Fluent Validations. Error: Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767457/fluent-validations-error-validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validatio) points to another way that using multiple providers can lead to the mentioned problem. Each provider can be configured to add an 'implicit required attribute to 'value types' (i.e. view model properties that aren't nullable). To resolve this particular issue, I could change my code to the following so that none of the providers add implicit required attributes:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(
    provider => provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false);


DependencyResolverValidatorFactory validatorFactory =
    new DependencyResolverValidatorFactory();

FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider validatorFactoryProvider =
    new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(validatorFactory);

validatorFactoryProvider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(validatorFactoryProvider);


DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Answer (score 14):

My case was that I had

```
.NotEmpty()
```

and

```
.NotNull()
```

at the same time, only one is needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using FluentValidation side by side with DataAnnotations this can happen.

When FluentValidation is in action you may need to remove DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider from the registered ModelValidatorProviders in Application_Start method.

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(); 
// Remove data annotations validation provider 
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.OfType<DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>().First());
```

Comment: Saved me from wasting a load more time...thanks this exactly fixes the issue raised in the way you described

Answer (score 0):

Please, update the web.config file :

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had added both NotEmpty and Length conditions to the validation rules at the same time.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Code).NotEmpty().Length(1, 10);
```

When I removed the NotEmpty condition the error disappeared.