# Fluent Validation breaks in ASP .Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have been facing this issue a while and have tried all sorts of facets. Nothing worked out till now. This is what I have. I have a **Student.cs** domain model class.

```
   [FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(StudentViewModelValidator))]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    //Department Navigational Property
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

And a StudentViewModel Class :

```
//View Model
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "StudentName")]
    public String StudentFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", Student.FirstName, Student.LastName);
        }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match")]
    [Display(Name="Confirm Password")]
    public String C_Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }

}
```

The Department Model class looks like :

```
   public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage="Department Name cannot be empty")]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Code cannot be empty")]
    public String DepartmentCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The FluentValidation Rules look like :

```
    public class StudentViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Student>
{
    public StudentViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("First Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^\D*$").WithMessage("Special characters and numbers are not allowed in First Name");
        RuleFor(m => m.LastName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Last Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^\D*$").WithMessage("Special characters and numbers are not allowed in Last Name");
        RuleFor(m => m.UserName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("User Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^a-zA-Z0-9\.\$").WithMessage("Only . and $ are allowed special characters in a user name");
        RuleFor(m => m.Password)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password is required.")
            .Length(4, 10).WithMessage("Password should be 4 to 10 characters long")
            .Matches(@".*\d{2}").WithMessage("Password should contain at least 2 digits")
            .Matches(@".*a-zA-Z").WithMessage("Password should contain at least one albhabet")
            .Matches(@"[\.\$\~\&]").WithMessage("Allowed special characters in a password are . $ ~ &");
   
    }
}
```

The validation keeps on breaking saying

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: regex

at `Password` field.

[image]

The View looks like :

```
  @model MvcApplication4.Models.Student

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Create a record</strong></legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="createDetails" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

**Update**

If I put these lines at `Application_Start()`

```
//var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory());
            //ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider);
            //DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
            //fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
```

Then the validation breaks at `LastName` Field.

[image]

Please help me through.

Comment: Does it work with only one .matches in the password validation?

Comment: No , it does not. It still shows an error in LastName. When I comment that code block for LastName out from FluentValidator , it shows error for FirstName.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be due to multiple number of value is set for same key

As ValidatonMessage is a dictionary type.

Remove all the decoration/data annotation on the viewmodel and use the fluentvalidator,its going to work.

Please refer to

[Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746186/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique)