# Override Required data attribute in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm creating an mvc app in asp.net. I've created viewModel with dataAttribute Required on this member, in order to get Validation message when I post my model to my controller. This is working fine.

Now I want to override the Validate method in order to specify a translation for the errorMessage. I'm working with a custom framework to get translation for a key.

I have to override the Required dataAttribute in order to get it working with expressive annotation.

Here is the code

ViewModel

```
public class SocietyInformationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "5614")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I put the translationKey in my ErrorMessage

After that, I've created a custom ModelValidator and a custom ModelValidatorProvider

ModelValidator

```
public class LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidator : ModelValidator
{
    private ModelValidator _innerValidator;
    private ModelMetadata _metadata;

    public LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidator(ModelValidator innerValidator, ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext)
        : base(metadata, controllerContext)
    {
        _innerValidator = innerValidator;
        _metadata = metadata;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
    {
        Service.TranslationService LocalizationManager = new Service.TranslationService();

        // execute the inner validation which doesn't have localization
        var results = _innerValidator.Validate(container);

        // convert the error message (which should be the localization resource key) to the localized value through the ILocalizationResourceProvider
        return results.Select((result) =>
        {
            string message = result.Message;
            int key = 0;

            if (Int32.TryParse(result.Message, out key))
                message = LocalizationManager.Get(key, "");

            return new ModelValidationResult() { Message = string.Format(message, _metadata.DisplayName) };
        });
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        Service.TranslationService LocalizationManager = new Service.TranslationService();
        var somerules = _innerValidator.GetClientValidationRules().ToList();

        foreach (var rule in somerules)
        {
            int key = 0;
            if (rule.ErrorMessage != null && rule.ErrorMessage.Length >= 3 && rule.ErrorMessage.Length <= 5 && Int32.TryParse(rule.ErrorMessage, out key))
                rule.ErrorMessage = LocalizationManager.Get(key, "");
        }

        return somerules;
    }
}
```

ModelValidatorProvider

```
public class LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    public LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        var validators = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
        var cnt = validators.Count();
        var result = new List<LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidator>();
        foreach (var validator in validators)
        {
            result.Add(new LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidator(validator, metadata, context));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And now I call the RegisterModelProviders in the global.asax on applicationStart

```
private void RegisterModelProviders()
    {
        // register the model metadata provider
        //ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();

        //// register the model validation provider
        var provider = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider)).FirstOrDefault();

        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

        if (provider != null)
        {
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(provider);
        }

        //ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
        provider = new LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider();
        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
    }
```

When doing like this, on execution, I've got the following exception

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: required

So I search on the web and I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746186/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique) with comments that say that I've to modify my web.config and set to false the ClientValidationEnabled key. I did it, and the error was gone, but my modelValidor is no more called...

I'm a little bit lost, any help is welcome

====== Update =======

After looking a lot on stack, I found that when using Ninject, it'will add NinjectDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider. That why I've got the message

> The following validation type was seen more than once: required

So I try to remove NinjectDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider but I can't find any solution for that.

====== Update 2 =======

In order to fix previous problems, I download Ninject.Web.Mvc project on github and include it in my solution. Then, I remove this line (from the MvcModule.cs)

```
this.Kernel.Bind<ModelValidatorProvider>().To<NinjectDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>();
```

I know it's not the best solution, but it's the only one that I've found

Comment: Why not just use a resource file?

Comment: Like I say, I use a custom framework to get the translation.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple providers provide the same validators it will register the same rules multiple times that's why its causing an error.

Try this:

```
private void RegisterModelProviders()
{
    var provider = new LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider();
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
    provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't have `provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;` So I try to put this in the constructor `public LocalizableDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider() : base()
        {
            AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
        }` but this doesn't work.