# Fluent Validation validator results in an error before validation code is even added to it

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm trying out Fluent Validation using the Contoso University project.

So I've added a validator attribute to an existing class:

```
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public abstract class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My `PersonValidator` doesn't do anything yet:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
    }
}
```

But when I access the create page for a Student my debugger stops on the `EditorFor` line....

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, 
      new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

….and I get an error:

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type was seen more than once:
>   required

I don't appear to have the same validation on the same element more than once, so why am I getting the error? 
Can Fluent Validation work alongside MVC's built in validation?

Comment: Looks very similar to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746186/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique#comment26469383_9746186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would add an implicit required validator to a string field, but the problem went away when I configured the Fluent Validation Provider to not add implicit required validators in my `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider 
    => provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false);
```

I didn't want to change the behaviour of any existing data annotations so that is all I added

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you use FluentValidation with DataAnnotations. Try to do something like this in Application_Start

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false);
var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory());
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider);
```

Comment: I suspect that I got the same error because I added this code as well as the standard `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure()` rather than instead of it. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#asp-net-mvc-5) page, you can try removing the DataAnnotations validations.

> **Compatibility with ASP.NET’s built-in Validation** By default, after FluentValidation is executed then any other validator providers will
>   also have a chance to execute as well. This means you can mix
>   FluentValidation with DataAnnotations attributes (or any other ASP.NET
>   ModelValidatorProvider implementation).
>
> If you want to disable this behaviour so that FluentValidation is the
>   only validation library that executes, you can set the
>   RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes to false in your
>   application startup routine:
>
> ```
> services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => {
>  fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
> });
> ```
>
> Note If you do set
>   RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes to false then
>   support for IValidatableObject will also be disabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This says you can mix FluentValidation with DataAnnotations attributes. My experience says you can't.